# return array from function php

Tags: php, arrays

I need this function to return an array. When I call the function it is printing the array, but when I use `return $finalResult` in the function, it is only printing the first array.

---

```
function readData($file)
{
    $finalResult = array();
    $inputText = file_get_contents($file);
    $textLines = explode("\n", $inputText);
    foreach ($textLines as $line)
    {
        $expLine = explode("\t", $line);
        if (count($expLine) < 8)
        {
            # The line does not have enough items, deal with error
            //echo "Item " . (isset($expLine[0]) ? $expLine[0]." " : "") . "ignored             because of errors\n";
            continue;
        }
        $finalResult = array(
            "title" => $expLine[0],
            "author" => $expLine[1],
            "isbn" => $expLine[2],
            "hardcover" => $expLine[3],
            "hc-quantity" => $expLine[4],
            "softcover" => $expLine[5],
            "sc-quantity" => $expLine[6],
            "e-book" => $expLine[7],
        );
        $arr = $finalResult;
        print_r($arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the print_r outside of the loop } and then change it to return... Where you have $arr=$finalResult; use array merge to add them together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You mush merge or push array to $finalResult see sammple

```
function readData($file){

    $finalResult = array();


    $inputText = file_get_contents($file);


    $textLines = explode("\n", $inputText);


    foreach($textLines as $line) {

    $expLine  = explode("\t", $line);

    if (count($expLine) < 8) {
        # The line does not have enough items, deal with error
        //echo "Item " . (isset($expLine[0]) ? $expLine[0]." " : "") . "ignored             because of errors\n";
        continue;
    }
    //Here []
    $finalResult[] = array(  
        "title" =>$expLine[0],
        "author"      => $expLine[1],
        "isbn"        => $expLine[2],  
        "hardcover"   => $expLine[3],
        "hc-quantity" => $expLine[4],
        "softcover"   => $expLine[5],
        "sc-quantity" => $expLine[6],
        "e-book"      => $expLine[7],

    );
    //$arr=$finalResult;
    //print_r($arr);        
    }
    return $finalResult;  
    }
```

Comment: This returns an indexed array of arrays?

Comment: It return all array you are built.. You can print_r returned value and checkit out :)

Answer (score -2):

As described in my comment above

```
function readData($file){

    $arr         = array();
    $finalResult = array();
    $inputText   = file_get_contents($file);
    $textLines   = explode("\n", $inputText);

    foreach($textLines as $line) {
        $expLine  = explode("\t", $line);
        if (count($expLine) < 8) {
            # The line does not have enough items, deal with error
            //echo "Item " . (isset($expLine[0]) ? $expLine[0]." " : "") . "ignored             because of errors\n";
            continue;
        }
        $finalResult = array(
            "title" =>$expLine[0],
            "author"      => $expLine[1],
            "isbn"        => $expLine[2],  
            "hardcover"   => $expLine[3],
            "hc-quantity" => $expLine[4],
            "softcover"   => $expLine[5],
            "sc-quantity" => $expLine[6],
            "e-book"      => $expLine[7],
        );
        $arr=array_merge($arr, $finalResult);
    }

    return $arr;
}
```